# C# .NET Socket connection issue - Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am having the following issue:

Once I close my WM6 application and then try to start it again i get this error:
**Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.TcpListener.Start()
...**

I think this is due to the time interval for the connection to timeout, so I would like to close all open conections and force it to create a new connection, is this the correct way to proceed or is there a different way to handle this?

Here is the code used to start listening:

```
/// <summary>
/// Listens Asynchronously to Clients, creates a recieveMessageHandler to process the read.
/// 
/// Check WIKI, TODOS
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public void Listen()
{
    myTcpListener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        //blocks until a client has connected to the server
        try
        {
            TcpClient myTcpClient = myTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            //Test if it's necessary to create a client
            ClientConnection client = new ClientConnection(myTcpClient, new byte[myTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize]);

            // Capture the specific client and pass it to the receive handler
            client.NetworkStream.BeginRead(client.Data, 0, myTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize, r => receiveMessageHandler(r, client), null);
        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Close myTcpListener on shutdown.

Comment: I do, however I am calling some Dlls that sometimes crash the application and the shutdown code is not called.

Comment: You need to better handle that error. By just crashing out & leaving your unmanaged resources laying around, you get this error. Although the CLR handles memory management for you for managed objects, you need to do it for unmanaged objects, such as files & networks connections.

Comment: The problem that I have is that I don't have a way to handle the this party DLLs, also the user can crash the application. I am open to suggestions on how to handle third party crashes and how to handle the user going to the task manager and closing the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your server socket is likely in the TIME_WAIT state.

You can access the underlying [ServerSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.server%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and then use [SetSocketOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.setsocketoption%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and specify [ReuseAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Ill give that a try... I find that Compact Framework has some quirks with sockets, so Ill try and see if that is available.

Comment: So after the creation of the listner I should do:
myTcpListener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess here that `ClientConnection` is your DLL, because I don't see that already included in the CF.

You don't really need that, though, if you declare [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker(); // required
```

To make your code really slick, you should also create your very own [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class:

```
public class WmTcpEventArgs : EventArgs {

  private string data;

  public WmTcpEventArgs(string text) {
    data = text;
  }

  public string Data { get { return data; } }

}
```

Very simple. With this new **WmTcpEventArgs** class and, you should be all set to receive your data that could post to something like a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) control:

```
private void NetworkResponder(object sender, WmTcpEventArgs e) {
  textBox1.Text = e.Data;
}
```

Instead of coding a `while(true)` in your code, I prefer to include a little Boolean variable

```
private bool abortListener;
```

The code would look something like this:

```
public void Listen() {
  listener.Start();
  while (!abortListener) {
    try {
      using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()) {
        int MAX = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        using (var stream = client.GetStream()) {
          Byte[] buffer = new Byte[MAX];
          int len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, MAX);
          if (0 < len) {
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, len);
            MethodInvoker method = delegate { NetworkResponder(this, new WmTcpEventArgs(data)); };
            abortListener = ((form1 == null) || form1.IsDisposed);
            if (!abortListener) {
              form1.Invoke(method);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception err) {
      Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
    } finally {
      listener.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Notice you are still catching your Exceptions, but you also stop the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).